# Can you explain why I can make a function expression from the variable of another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, expression

Can you explain why I can make a function expression from the variable of another function  in javascript?

Exemple:

```
let test = function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}

test.hello = function(){
    console.log("Hello");
}

test();
//hi

test.hello();
//hello
```

Each function do different things, but the function "test.hello()" use the variable "test" from the first function.

I don't have to create a new variable for the second function "test.hello()".

I want to know why javascript allow us to do that. If you can use a lot of detail, it would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Functions are objects and objects can have properties assigned to them. If those properties are also functions, those properties can be called as functions. That's all that's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how you would go about creating properties and methods for a JS object. JavaScript allows you to do that so you can do Object Oriented Programming. Likely you're used to other languages that require you to define a function and its' properties and methods, but with JS it's as easy as you demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.

One more thing.
It is just useless to do that like the last snippet above.

It is better to do that like that:

```
let test = function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}

let hello = function(){
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

It is more clear in my opinion. Use two variable instead.